# getting incorrect value from excel using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

in excel the value of column is 10101101010000000000 but when im reading it in java using POI the value is changed to 10101101009999999000, can anyone give me an idea on whats going on and how can i get the exact values from the excel.
i've tried setting the celltype as string and use `cell.getStringCellValue()` and also this `new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString()` but im still not getting the same value as with the excel

here's my code

```
List<BankClassVo> data = new ArrayList<BankClassVo>();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(Constant.VALIDATION_REFERENCE_FILE_PATH + Constant.BANK_CLASSIFICATION_REF_FILE + ".xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(1);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();


    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        BankClassVo vo = new BankClassVo ();


            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0) {
                    vo.setsClass(new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString());
                }
                else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 1) {
                    vo.setClassification(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }
            }

        data.add(vo);
    }

    myWorkBook.close();
    return data;
```

Comment: You should probably add the code you're using to read the column

Comment: ok, ive added my code

Comment: I suggest you to read it as a string and then check if it's reading correctly.

Comment: @ Uma Kanth, yes ive already done that and still not reading correctly

Comment: XLSX stores as XML, so text. Just to make sure the problem is in Java: unzip the contents of your XLSX file and open `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` to see what the value actually is.
Other than that, it looks like an overflow issue, perhaps in your `BankClassVo` class.
Maybe first send `cell.getStringCellValue()` to `System.out`.

Comment: What formatting rules do you have applied to the cell in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MathContext` and `RoundingMode`. [Ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html)

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue(), new MathContext(10 , RoundingMode.CEILING));
System.out.println(value.toPlainString());
```